# Strange output from Docker image/container?

Tags: image, shell, docker, command-line, containers

I am fairly new to Docker and am trying to run an image and when I do I would usually get “inside” the image if that makes sense, where i can access different directories that i have made inside.

However, when I have done it recently I have gotten the following output:

```
top - 15:49:10 up 2:36, 0 users, load average: 0.65, 0.70, 0.71
Tasks: 1 total, 1 running, 0 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 5.9 us, 2.8 sy, 0.2 ni, 89.2 id, 1.8 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.1 si, 0.0 st
KiB Mem : 3930660 total, 370676 free, 1749516 used, 1810468 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 4076540 total, 4076540 free, 0 used. 1550316 avail Mem

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
1 root 20 0 36536 2968 2604 R 0.0 0.1 0:00.05 top -b -c

top - 15:49:13 up 2:36, 0 users, load average: 0.65, 0.70, 0.71
Tasks: 1 total, 1 running, 0 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 3.0 us, 2.6 sy, 0.0 ni, 94.2 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.2 si, 0.0 st
KiB Mem : 3930660 total, 366860 free, 1753244 used, 1810556 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 4076540 total, 4076540 free, 0 used. 1546536 avail Mem

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
1 root 20 0 36536 2968 2604 R 0.0 0.1 0:00.05 top -b -c^
```

from the following docker command:

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu-latest
```

I am running docker 17.12 on ubuntu 16.04. At this time If I could receive a solution without having to post the dockerfile I will, due to certain information being present in the file.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is your actual question? If you want to run a container without getting "inside" the container add the -d flag.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear. The output above is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to get the /bin/bash instead

Comment: Try this: sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu-latest /bin/bash
Actually it's what chris means.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. This is my output from that:                                                                  top: unknown option '/'
Usage:
  top -hv | -bcHiOSs -d secs -n max -u|U user -p pid(s) -o field -w [cols]

Answer (score 0):

when a container launches it executes a binary which can be defined within the image or overridden with the cli using the entrypoint and command arguments.

see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd vs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

In this case it looks like you've launched your container to run 'top' automatically which is why it's launching and executing top as pid 1 instead of an interactive bash session.  If you could paste just your Dockerfile Entrypoint and CMD args it would be possible to know exactly what's happening but you should be able to override them via the cli with:

sudo docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash -i -t ubuntu-latest

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't override it, I'm not actually using any entrypoints/cmd as of yet. What I'm really looking to get is where I can get in the image and can use shell commands if that makes sense. All of a sudden though, this whole top this just came out of nowhere.

Comment: I entered the command wrong and it worked. Thanks very much. What is the proper name for these "top" processes though?